# What should I install to use command line tools like cl and lib with visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, build-tools

[image: here are the packages I installed]

I'm using the VS2019 dev prompt to run a lib command, I need it to use the tinycc lib, the command is found here:

https://github.com/TinyCC/tinycc/blob/dev/win32/tcc-win32.txt#L60

This command worked with MSVC 2017.

I'm unable to understand why the command doesn't work and what package I would need to install to make it work, I don't see any relevant package there.

Comment: I believe you have selected what you need. Although you did select the 2017 build tools and not the 2019.

Comment: Did you include the MSBuild component? Also, are you getting errors? If so, what are they? Does `lib` and `cl` exist in your installation directory?

Comment: msbuild is installed. @drescherjm I know, I did that because I use libs compiled with vc 2017

Comment: @ChrisMM yes cl.exe and lib.exe are here in Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\

Comment: Are you getting errors? "command doesn't work" doesn't say too much.

Comment: @ChrisMM 'lib' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: If you echo the `%PATH%` in the developer command prompt, is the path correct? `lib` works fine for me, and I have a similar setup to you (2019 instead of 2017 build tools though). For me, lib is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\Hostx86\x86\lib.exe`

Comment: Your Visual Studio 2019 command prompt probably does not have the correct path set for the 2017 toolchain. You will have to fix that or create your own shortcut with the correct path.

Comment: you're right, the paths are incorrect... shouldn't that be reported to microsoft?

Comment: A developer command prompt shortcut automatically sets the correct paths for the compiler and tools, and for any required headers and libraries. You must set these environment values yourself if you use a regular Command Prompt window. For more information, I suggest you should refer to the [Set the Path and Environment Variables for Command-Line Builds.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/setting-the-path-and-environment-variables-for-command-line-builds?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I'm not using a regular prompt window, I'm using a dev command prompt, "developer command prompt for VS 2019"

Comment: I assume that MS probably only includes in the PATH the latest build tools, as opposed to those that you selected on the install. You can probably modify _C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat_ or one of the other bats to load the appropriate PATH for you.

Comment: yes that was my thought too. although I just called lib.exe by cd'ing the right dir, it was easier that way

Comment: ***I assume that MS probably only includes in the PATH the latest build tools, as opposed to those that you selected on the install.*** I agree. Maybe if the OP would file a bug report they could create links to each compiler version. Although as a programmer it's easy to do this yourself if you find yourself in this situation.